# How to share "computed" methods across a Vue.js application

Tags: javascript, vue.js, mixins

I have a Vue.js application which loads a list of items, and each item is passed as a `prop` to a Vue component.

I figured out that by using `mixins` I can share common component properties, like `computed`,`created`, etc.

Now, I'm trying to sort the list of items and can't figure out how I would access each component's computed properties to apply sorting/filtering. How can I accomplish this?

**Items**

```
[{
  price: 10,
  qty: 2
}, {
  price: 8,
  qty: 3
}]
```

**Mixin - ./Cost.js**

```
export default {
  computed: {
     cost () {
        return this.price * this.qty;
     }
  }
}
```

**Component (which works as expected) - ./Product.vue**

```
import Cost from './Cost.js'
export default {
   name: 'product-item',
   props: ['product'],
   mixins: [Cost]
}
```

> How would you access the computed properties, or restructure this setup?

**List component**

```
<template>
  <div id="list">
     <div v-for="product in sorted" :product="product">Cost: {{ cost }} </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import ProductItem from './Product.vue'
export default {
   components: { ProductItem },
   created: () {
      this.items = [...] // as noted above
   },
   computed: {
       sorted () {
           return this.items.sort( (a,b) => b.cost - a.cost); // cost is not accessible!
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

Comment: you sort `this.items`, but this.items is `[{
  price: 10,
  qty: 2
}, {
  price: 8,
  qty: 3
}]`, not one array whose each element is `ProductItem` component. Absolutely it will not have cost property.

Comment: Yes, I know... Looking for ideas to access their computed properties somehow

Comment: one solution: use attribute=ref like `<div v-for="product in sorted" :product="product" ref="test">`, then `computed: () {
     return this.$refs.test.sort( (a,b) => b.cost - a.cost); // cost is not accessible!
   }`

Comment: Shouldn't `computed` return an object with methods? `computed: { sorted() { return this.items.sort( (a,b) => b.cost - a.cost); }}`

Comment: Personally I just feel you should have an order field called `cost` in the return; i.e. price, qty and `cost`. Since, this is an attribute of the data and not of the component.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `vuex`.  Your `vuex store` will provide a `getters` object that can be wrapped into multiple components’ native `computed` objects, or accessed directly.  Your code will be DRY, reactive, cached, and maintainable.

From my experience, once you need to go beyond `child-parent` data relationships, `vuex`, `store`, and `shared state` are the way to go.  Once you get the hang of it, it is downright magical how your app evolves.

It is beyond scope of the question to show how to install `vuex`.  Visit https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html to see how getters are similar to computed properties, with the value of being shared between components.  The official Vuex guide will also demonstrate how to initialize your Vue instance with the store.

Here are some snippets to show you the *actors* in the `vuex` system.

## Store and State

```
// state definition (basically a shared reactive 'data' object that lives outside components)
state:{
    message:'Hello'
}

// the store getters are declared as methods and accessed as properties (just like component/computed)
getters:{
    message: state => return state.message
}
```

## Accessing From Components

```
// component 1 wraps getter
computed:{
    message(){
      return this.$store.getters.message
    }
}

// component 2 also wraps getter
computed:{
    message(){
      return this.$store.getters.message
    }
}
```

```html
// templates can also use getters directly
<div>{{$store.getters.message}}</div>

// If message was wrapped, you can simply use the computed property
<div>{{message}}</div>
```

Once you start using `vuex`, all sorts of other treasures start to emerge, such as the developer tools in Chrome, undo/redo support, simple refactoring of state, time-travel debugging, app persistence, etc.  There are also shortcuts for adding multiple store getters into your computed properties.

Comment: if child-parent data relationships, probably provide/inject will be one option.

Comment: Even official Vue docs advise against that architecture vs vuex for this application IIRC. But inject does provide implementation decoupling; tThat’s another issue though.

Comment: Thanks - can you point me to docs showing an example of "`object that can be wrapped into multiple components’ native computed objects`"? I now have this data in a `store`, but unsure how to do what the `mixin` was  doing for me before with prototype-like properties.

Comment: Sure, I will add an example to answer.

Comment: @d-_-b I added some examples.  The time spend on Vuex will have more payoffs than any other efforts you put into Vue development.

Comment: "As of Vue `3.0`, the getter's result is not cached as the computed property does. This is a known issue that requires Vue `3.1`" https://next.vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#getters

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by @Sphinx, you could use a `ref` to access the child component.

For example:

```
<template>
  <div id="list">
     <product-item v-for="product in sorted" :product="product" :ref="product"></product-item>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import ProductItem from './Product.vue'
export default {
   components: { ProductItem }, 
   data: () => ({
       hidrated: false,
       items: []
   })
   created() {
       this.items = [...] // as noted above
   },
   mounted() {
       this.hidrated = true
   },
   computed: {
       sorted () {
           if (!this.hidrated && !Object.keys(this.$refs).length) {
               // handle initial state, before rendered
               return this.items
           }
           return Object.values(this.$refs)[0]
               .sort((a,b) => b.cost - a.cost)
               .map(c => c.product)
       }
   }
}
</script>
```

This is assuming you have no other `ref` in your `List Component`.

You also have to check if the component is rendered first, here I use `hidrated` to flag when the component is mounted.

Comment: you can directly uses ref="product", then `this.$refs.product` will be one array. check [Vue Guide: ref](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#ref), it states *When used on elements/components with v-for, the registered reference will be **an Array** containing **DOM nodes** or **component instances**.*

Comment: Thanks @Sphinx for pointing that out. Tested it myself and updated my answers.

Comment: probably `return this.$refs.product
               .sort((a,b) => b.cost - a.cost)
               .map(c => c.product)` will be better. And you should update the description relevantly.

Comment: `this.$refs.product` returns `undefined`. `this.$refs` returns `{[object Object]: Array[2]}`